# Store media in internal storage using download manager

Tags: android, uri, android-download-manager, android-internal-storage

Want to store music file inside getFilesDir() using Uri. I had tried to store by this way

```
Uri Download_Uri = Uri.parse(songBean.vSongsFileName);
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Download_Uri);
mDownloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
request.setAllowedOverRoaming(false);
request.setTitle(songBean.vTitle);
request.setDescription("Downloading File");

    try {
    request.setDestinationUri(Uri.parse(createDirectory("tmp.mp3").getPath()));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    downloadReference = mDownloadManager.enqueue(request);
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        }
    }, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
```

Method for the create directory inside internal storage

```
public File createDirectory(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), filename);
    Log.i("Tag", "createDirectory: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
    return file;
}
```

Not able to store the file in internal storage.`request.setDestinationUri(Uri.parse(createDirectory("tmp.mp3").getPath()));` throwing `not a file uri` error.Please help me out for this

Comment: I see no problem description. Nor a question.

Comment: I faced this type of issue so I post it if anyone had done this

Comment: Which issue did you face? You did not describe an issue/problem.

Comment: `createDirectory()`. That does NOT create a directory. You can check with file.exists().

Comment: .`It throwing not a file uri error.` What is `it`? Please come to the point.

Comment: I will check for this but my problem is not able to store media in internal storage using download manager

Comment: `request.setDestinationUri(Uri.parse(createDirectory("tmp.mp3").getPath()));` throws error

Comment: Does not matter now. Even if you would use  file provider you would use that function too. So make it work first. And if you have that catch you should return and stop. And display a toast to the user saying so.

Answer (score 0):

The getFilesDir() is private internal storage for your app only. You cannot ask another app to put files there as it has no access.

For DownloadManager use external storage.

Comment: is there any solution to store media in internal storage?

Comment: Use a FileProvider.

Comment: can you suggest me link or some idea for it?